# How can I write custom servlet context init method

Tags: servlets

I wish to set up a few application wide variables with servletContext.setAttributes on servlet context initialization phase .How can I achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement `javax.servlet.SevletContextListener` which gets a callback when `javax.servlet.ServletContext` is initialized.

**Here is the example:**

```
public class MyServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener
{
   public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce)
   {
       ServletContext sc = sce.getServletContext();
       //do your initialization here.
       sc.setAttribute(.....);
   }

   public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce)
   {
       ServletContext sc = sce.getServletContext();
       //do your cleanup here

   }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `MyServletContextListener` be annotaed with `@WebListener`? See [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebListener.html).

Comment: Definitely you have to define your Listener somewhere. Either by 1) Annoatation 2) In web.xml or 3) In TLD.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to tie your logic closer to the servlet (and not use a listener), you can override the servlets `init` method. Like so:

```
@Override
public void init() throws ServletException {
    ServletContext sc = getServletContext();

    // Store our attribute(s)!
    // Check first to make sure it hasn't already been set by another Servlet instance.
    if (sc.getAttribute("key") == null)
        sc.setAttribute("key", "value");
}
```

And you don't have to call through to `super.init(config)`. See [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html#init%28%29).