# Custom startup in servlet

Tags: java, scala, servlets, akka, atmosphere

I'm creating an atmosphere servlet application, which uses the following servlet in web.xml https://atmosphere.java.net/nonav/apidocs/org/atmosphere/cpr/AtmosphereServlet.html.

When this service starts up I would like to start to an Akka actor system and have it available throughout the life of the application.

How is this done?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  This should be a pretty straight forward answer provided you did a little work yourself which I'm guessing you have not. Show some work/thought first before coming here for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you want to do is initialize an actor system within the servlet context. [This question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338132/how-can-i-write-custom-servlet-context-init-method) should help. Don't forget to include the `ContextListener` in your `web.xml`.