# Servlet: OutOfMemory Error

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, netbeans, out-of-memory

I am writing a Servlet. Here is my code:

```
private LinkedList <HashSet> completeHashList;
    private LinkedList<String>hashStr;

    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config)
    {
        completeHashList = new LinkedList<HashSet>();
        hashStr = new LinkedList<String>();

        System.out.println("Hash Loading started");

        try
        {
            //Read the Hash File
            String str = "";
            File inputFile = new File("E:/Amazon HashFile/Hash.txt");

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
            int hashNumber=1;

            while((str=br.readLine())!=null)
            {
                HashSet<String>lineCollector = new HashSet<String>();
                int lastIndex = 0;

                hashStr.add(str);

                for(int i=0;i<=str.length();i=i+3)
                {
                    lastIndex = i;
                    try
                    {
                        String stringPiece = str.substring(i, i+3);
                    //  pw.println(stringPiece);
                        lineCollector.add(stringPiece);
                    }
                    catch(Exception arr)
                    {
                        String stringPiece = str.substring(lastIndex, str.length());
                        //  pw.println(stringPiece);
                        lineCollector.add(stringPiece);
                    }
                }

                completeHashList.add(lineCollector);

                System.out.println(hashNumber);
                hashNumber++;
            }

            System.out.println("Hash Loading Done");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Here I get the following error.

```
    Exception in thread "http-apr-8080-exec-2" Exception in thread "ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1960)
    at analyzer.SiteAnalizer.init(SiteAnalizer.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1228)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:836)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:964)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1824)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1242)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1400)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1389)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

The file I am reading is 77MB in size, Java can easily store that kind of file in memory. I did this with the desktop Java version of this application as well. But here, it crashes!!

It is targeting to the code piece

What if wrong here?

Apart from that, I need this code to run as soon as the `Servlet` is loaded. But this is running once the `Servlet` is being called from a `JSP` page. That is not what I need, `Servlet` should run this code and wait for the `doGet()` and `doPost()` requests.

**Update**

I am running this inside Netbeans. So how to adjust the VM Heap size for Tomcat there?

Answer (score 0):

Probably just increase Xmx option for JVM.

I use this settings for JVM while developing web applications:

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=384m -Xms768m -Xmx1536m -XX:MaxNewSize=384m -XX:NewSize=384m
```

Of course it depends on project size.

Comment: Java can easily hold that amount in JVM. It is 77 MB

Comment: I think by default max heap is 64mb on java application, if -Xmx is not provided with different value.

Comment: OK. How to do this in Netbeans?

Answer (score 0):

After looking to your code, it really simple and should not raise that kind of errors, it could happened. so i suggest you to look at the `JVM memory arguments`.

You need to take a look at this. actually you can set the as much memory as you want to your JVM :

```
-Xmx2048m -> this param to set the max memory that the JVM can allocate
-Xms1024m -> the init memory that JVM will allocate on the start up
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M -> this for the max Permanent Generation memory
-XX:MaxNewSize=  -> this need to be 40% from your Xmx value
-XX:NewSize=614m -> this need to be 40% from your Xmx value
```

Also its not a `77MB` that will load into memory, from your code, you have a 3 Collections

- completeHashList
- hashStr
- lineCollector

all of these collection load the same data and cache them.

Comment: OK. How to increase the JVM for Tomcat in Netbeans?

Comment: Go to you `serve -> right click -> select Properties -> open Platform tab`, then add the above arguments separated by white space inside `JVM Option` text field.

Answer (score 0):

*The file I am reading is 77MB in size, Java can easily store that kind of file in memory. I did this with the desktop Java version of this application as well. But here, it crashes!!*

Look at your container(server) configuration. I suppose you should increase maximum heap size.

*Servlet should run this code and wait for the doGet() and doPost() requests. How can I do this?*

[Here is how to get work done on initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338132/how-can-i-write-custom-servlet-context-init-method)

You can save your data somewhere in memory or disk and then return it by servlet (in do... method).

Comment: I can't save on disk. Requirement is to load from memory.